# eb : The term 'eb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django Application with AWS beanstalk following this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Everything works up till this point:

```
~/ebdjango$ eb init -p python-3.6 student-archive
```

When I run that line of code I get this error:

```
eb : The term 'eb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ eb init -p python-3.6 studentarchive
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (eb:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What could be some causes of this?
Here's my django.config:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: StudentArchive/wsgi.py
```

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
autopep8==1.5.7
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
certifi==2021.5.30
distlib==0.3.2
Django==3.2.6
filelock==3.0.12
pipenv==2021.5.29
platformdirs==2.2.0
pycodestyle==2.7.0
pytz==2021.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.1
toml==0.10.2
virtualenv==20.7.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.6
```

Comment: Seems you need to [install awsebcli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to install [awsebcli](https://pypi.org/project/awsebcli/) to be able to use the `eb` [CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html).

```
python3 -m pip install awsebcli
```

More info regarding installation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-advanced.html